# init_nloptr.c:35:19: fatal error: nlopt.h: No such file or directory

Tags: r, compiler-errors, nlopt

I am installing lme4 in R, but the mentioned problem occurred. I saw answers for Linux and Ubuntu. I am running on Windows, and I receive a fatal error message as shown. Can someone help, pls?

compilation terminated.

```
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: init_nloptr.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'nloptr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/nloptr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/MARK'S~1/SURP/Thesis/Software/R/Packages/nloptr_1.2.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Please, could you share the output of `sessionInfo()` ?